# Django + Using a local database

Tags: django, database, postgresql

Once a day a database is pushed to my server where I am hosting my Django application. I want to use this local postgreSQL database for queries the user can perform and the pre-installed sqlite3 database to hold users.

I've tried integrating the local postgreSQL database and successfully migrated the table schema but I have no idea how to push all of the data.

Should I attempt to create a fixture and upload this data daily or is there another way I am not seeing.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You can create a script to migrate the prod data to local database. Just use `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` commands. No need of fixtures here.

Comment: I have the data in a local database where my django app is running. I having trouble accessing the data from django.

Comment: Since I already have all of the data locally. My plan is to create a fixture of the local data and migrate that to my models. The interesting part is that data is pushed to my server daily. So I either need to automate the process of creating fixtures of the new data and pushing into my models. Another option, my co-worker suggested I could set up a REST API to push to new data into my models. Any thoughts???